# Invert singular matrix for design of experiments and regression

Tags: normal-distribution, least-squares, random-variable, experiment-design, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix, $X'X$, which is singular meaning that I cannot invert it. I need the inverse of this matrix to perform two independent things. I need it for the design of experiments, in R using optFederov() algorithm. Also I need it invertible for OLS.

I believe the two possible sources of singularity are:

**1.-** Many points lying in the same plane

**2.-** There are linear combinations between columns

I think it is the first problem. To solve the problem I have added very small random noise to each value of x, $x_{i}$, from a Normal Distribution such that $x_{i,noise} \sim N(0,0.001)$.

Apparently this trick makes the matrix invertible. However, I am not sure if this is a good approach. My thought is that it is good for OLS given that the esitmators will change veeery little, but not sure on the design of experiments, for example using a D-Efficiency design.

I would appreciate some suggestion regarding whether this is a good way to proceed or not!

Comment: Presumably $X$ is the design matrix.

Comment: @Scortchi yes, X is the full factorial design, but in order to obtain a D-optimal fractional factorial design I have to minimize $|(X'X)^{-1}|$ which indeed requires the inverse of $X'X$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse ?

Comment: If it is singular certainly it cannot be Doptimal, unless tjere are so few points that all designs are singular. You shpuld splve that problem rather than just perturb

Answer (score 2):

Rather than random noise, adding a small multiple of the identity matrix is the standard way to handle this in regression problems. It's equivalent to [ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). I.e $X^\prime X+\epsilon I$ is used in place of $X^\prime X$, for $\epsilon$ small, say 0.001 or 0.01. I'm not sure about the experimental design aspects.

Comment: Yes, but it wouldbebetter tofind out what whent wrong

Comment: This is a good point, but it would be well to explain that "$\epsilon$ small" is meaningful only when the columns of the design matrix have been standardized.